# Cannot re-use checkbox functions in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, ecmascript-6, mapping

I have a mapping function which shows JSON values into checkboxes, each checkbox triggers another 2 checkboxes, the JSON i am using have a min/max value which i made a function for to set min/max for checkbox selections in each section, both features works fine. The problem is however, that once the parent checkbox is clicked and it expands to show 2 functional checkboxes, then i redo the process where i click it to shrink it and click it again to expand it, the children checkboxes stops being clickable.

The checkbox values are passed as props from **Checkbox.js** to **Itemlist.js** where the fetch/map happens. Would Appreciate it if anyone can explain or demonstrate how this can be achieved.

React Live Snippet: https://codesandbox.io/embed/oo059p7q19?fontsize=14

**Checkbox.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Checkbox.css";

class Checkboxes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentData: 0,
      limit: 2,
      checked: false
    };
  }

  selectData(id, event) {
    let isSelected = event.currentTarget.checked;
    if (isSelected) {
      if (this.state.currentData < this.props.max) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData + 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (this.state.currentData > this.props.min) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData - 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = true;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const input2Checkboxes =
      this.props.options &&
      this.props.options.map(item => {
        return (
          <div className="inputGroup2">
            {" "}
            <div className="inputGroup">
              <input
                id={this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)}
                name="checkbox"
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={this.selectData.bind(
                  this,
                  this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)
                )}
              />
              <label
                htmlFor={this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)}
              >
                {item.name || item.description}{" "}
                {/** <img src={this.props.img} alt="" /> <span className="pricemod">{props.childprice} SAR</span>
                 */}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });

    return (
      <form className="form">
        <div>
          {/** <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>*/}
          <div className="inputGroup">
            <input
              id={this.props.childk + this.props.name}
              name="checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.checked}
              onChange={this.selectData.bind(
                this,
                this.props.childk + this.props.uniq
              )}
              onChange={() => {
                this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor={this.props.childk + this.props.name}>
              {this.props.name}{" "}
            </label>
          </div>{" "}
          {this.state.checked ? input2Checkboxes : undefined}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I debugged your code. You don't setState in the Checkbox component.
Take a look at selectData method. Conditions:

```
this.state.currentData < this.props.max
```

and

```
this.state.currentData > this.props.min
```

The conditions are true only once because min and max properties are too small (1 when I debugged), so the conditions are always false after first select.

Suitable solutions:

1. Delete

`event.preventDefault();
 event.currentTarget.checked = true;`
in else statments (Input is uncontrolled component)

2. Call `setState` in else statments.

Comment: I see, so what would be the suitable solution for this?

Comment: You should use `setState` instead of `event.currentTarget.checked = false`; Set checked flag can't update your UI because of React updates dom only after call `setState` or `forceUpdate`

Comment: @AlxL I'm a little wrong in my previous comment. Input is uncontrolled component, so you also can just delete `event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = true;` in else statments

Comment: When i removed event.preventDefault(); & event.currentTarget.checked = true; , it removed the feature i added which sets the minimum limit for the checkbox to 1, and the glitch which makes the checkbox unclickable still exists, you can check it here https://codesandbox.io/embed/oo059p7q19?fontsize=14